# How can I import all files of a particular extension from subdirectories and save them separately?

Tags: python, numpy, import, glob

I have a directory

```
* workingdir
  * raw_data
      * 2001
         - a.dat
         - b.dat
         - c.dat
      * 2002
         - d.dat
         - e.dat
         - f.data

       * 2003 etc.
```

How can I read these dat files into separate variables?

So far:

```
import os                 # Operating system interface
import glob               # For Unix style pathnames
import numpy as np        

workingdir = '/home/x/workingdir/'

#Directory for all raw data files
rawdatadir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.pardir, "raw_data")) 

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rawdatadir):
    for files in [f for f in files if f.endswith(".dat")]:
        print(os.path.join(rawdatadir, files))


But this is giving me

/home/x/workingdir/raw_data/a.dat
/home/x/workingdir/raw_data/b.dat
```

So,

1. How can I get the full path of all the files
2. And import them (np.fromfile?)
3. Any "smarter" way to do this?

I come from an R/dataframe background and would prefer to mimic something near that.

Comment: To find all those files, use https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob I'll promote this to answer

Comment: I promoted this to an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can get full path by replacing `os.path.join(rawdatadir, files)` with `os.path.join(root, files)`

`root` variable contains the directory path in which files listed in `files` are located.
Correct loop implementation would be:

Storing results can be done using `dict` if you want to access them by file name

```
results = {}

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rawdatadir):
    for file in filter(lambda f: f.endswith('.dat'), files):
        results[file] = np.fromfile(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Comment: Okay I see the dict now. Thanks! But I would like to store them separately. How can I?

Comment: AFAIK Python doesn't allow dynamic variable creation, you should put these into some kind of container.

Comment: How can I put it in a list instead?

Comment: `results.append(np.fromfile())` (assuming `results` is a `list`)

Comment: Thanks. I have never used dict before. I am used to accessing dataframes easily in R. How can I access one of the keys in the dict? Looks like it is importing one column only when I click in spyder. But I am not able to confirm...The files have 5 columns each..

Comment: Looks like I need a Pandas dataframe. Can you help me store data in that format? Looks like that is a near equivalent of dataframe in R. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe

Comment: You might want to try http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#basics-dataframe-from-dict

Answer (score 0):

Use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) to find all files in subdirectories, the walking over the list and storing names and content. Its `recursive` option allows the token `**` to match any path which includes subdirectories into the search.

```
from glob import iglob
import os.path
workingdir = '/home/x/workingdir/'

result = {}
for f in iglob(os.path.join(workingdir, './**/*.dat'), recursive=True):
    result[f] = np.fromfile(os.path.abspath(f))
```

This cute single generator also allows us to express this in a nice pythonic form

```
files = iglob(os.path.join(workingdir, './**/*.dat'), recursive=True)
result = {f: np.fromfile(os.path.abspath(f)) for f in files}
```

Comment: You probably don't even need os.path.abspath, but I don't have np right now, so I can't test that